# Ruby on Rails Scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scope

I'm creating a sticker album and i need to scope repeated stickers.
I still can't fully understand scopes in rails. How can i create a scope that gets all the repeated stickers from a user?

`Figurinha` has a `colada` boolean attribute, which means the sticker is placed or not in the album.

`Dep` is the players database, Figurinha get the name, avatar and others infos from `Dep` model.

`repetida` is the method I was trying to create to check if the `figurinha` is repeated or not.

A `figurinha` is repeated when `Figurinha` has another record with the same `user` and `dep` wich is already been `colada`

User.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :figurinhas
end
```

Figurinha.rb

```
class Figurinha < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :dep

  def repetida
    coladas = self.user.figurinhas.where(colada: true)
    colodas.map{|a| a.dep}.include?(self.dep)
  end

end
```

Dep.rb

```
class Dep < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :avatar
  validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"]

  belongs_to :partido, foreign_key: :partido, primary_key: :sigla

  def avatar_from_url(url)
    self.avatar = open(url)
  end
end
```

Comment: Dep is the players database, Figurinha get the name, avatar and others infos from Dep database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `figurinha` can only have one true `colada` per user you can try this :

```
scope :repetida, ->(user_id) { uniq.where(user_id: user_id, colada: false, dep_id: Figurinha.where(user_id: user_id, colada: true).pluck(:dep_id)) }
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Can you explain to me the use of pluck method?

Comment: you can read about pluck here http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck
it returns an array of attribute values. in your case the attribute is `dep_id`

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
def repetida
  coladas = self.user.figurinhas.where(colada: true)
  colodas.map{|a| a.dep}.include?(self.dep)
end
```

with:

```
scope :repetida, ->(user_id) {where(user_id: user_id).group(:dep_id).having("count(*) > 1").having("bool_or(colada) =true") }
```

and call should be:

```
Figurinha.repetida(User.first.id)
```

which is trying to select all `Figurinha` which belongs to `user_id` and then grouping them with `dep_id` so we now have groups of repeated `Figurinha` but we only need if the count of the group is > 1 to consider a duplicate.

Comment: We are almost there. The user can only have one figurinha of the same dep with colada=true.

Comment: ok, then you need to remove `colada=true` from the where statement

Comment: @ViniciusFontoura let's see if that work with you `having("bool_or(colada) =true")` we get all colada from the groups records and check if oring them will give us true that mean 1 of them is true which mean 1 of them is colada, and when you render your records skip the one with true(the main colada)

Comment: I'm getting this error now:
`SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: true: SELECT "figurinhas".* FROM "figurinhas" WHERE "figurinhas"."user_id" = ? GROUP BY "figurinhas"."dep_id" HAVING count(*) > 1 AND bool_or(colada) =true`

Comment: you are using sqllite then true and false is 1 and 0 replace true with 1

Comment: Im using SQLite in development, i think SQLite dont have bool_or function. I will change to postgre later and I will update you later on. Thank you